# Она свернула с шоссе и поскакала по узкой, неторной дорожке, которая действительно как будто направлялась к горам

Tags: синтаксис, вводные-слова, сравнение, причастный-оборот

Никак не могу понять, является ли "по дорожке, которая действительно как будто направлялась к горам" осложнением (если да, то каким)? По-моему, это сравнение, но вроде и ПО. Кажется, что нужно обособить слово "действительно", т. к. оно вводное. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

> Она свернула с шоссе и поскакала по узкой, неторной дорожке, которая действительно как будто направлялась к горам.

Comment: "Действительно" обособлять нет никаких причин, оно не вводное. Можно заменить на "и вправду" или "на самом деле". Вводные слова — те, которые буквально понять невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Она свернула с шоссе и поскакала по узкой неторной дорожке, которая действительно как будто направлялась к горам.

СПП с придаточным определительным "которая действительно как будто направлялась к горам", союзное слово КОТОРАЯ.

Действительно здесь наречие в роли обстоятельства.

КАК БУДТО - сравнительный союз со значением предположения (как будто направлялась).

По узкой неторной дорожке - запятую можно не ставить (неоднородные определения), при постановке запятой - сближение признаков, переход в однородные определения.